# Loop inside CompletableFuture to make async call

Tags: java, asynchronous, completable-future

I have a function like so

```
private CompletableFuture<Collection<Profiles>> getProfiles(QueryType query){
return supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                Collection<Profiles> profiles =
                        this.gateway.profiles(query);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new Exception("test", e);
            }
}
```

Now, when this function gets profiles, I want to iterate over the profiles and make another async call that hits another gateway and fetches further details based on ProfileID.

This is what I have -

```
public CompletableFuture<Collection<Results>> handleRequest(
            QueryType query) {
        CompletableFuture<Collection<Profiles>> profiles =
                getProfiles(query);
         profiles.thenCompose(
            //Iterate over all profiles and call another function that returns completable future with the argument profiles.ID
         )
}
```

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: `CompletableFuture` has `allOf` and `anyOf` methods for combining many `CompletableFuture`s. Is that how you want to group them?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis allOf returns CF<Void> which is annoying